# Stack as a Persistent Data Structure Implementation

Tags: java, object-oriented, stack, immutability

After reading some articles about immutability, I found out that there are [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). In the following, I implemented a stack as a persistent data structure.

What I like about the code in the current state

- it contains [no if-statements](https://francescocirillo.com/pages/anti-if-campaign)
- no method is longer than one line
- it works like recursion

## Implementation

The implementation is based on the abstraction `Stack`, which has two concrete data-types: `EmptyStack` and `NonEmptyStack`. A `Stack` needs to implement 4 methods as described below.

```java
public interface Stack<E> {

    /**
     * @return the number of elements
     */
    int size();

    /**
     * adds a new element to the top of the {@code Stack}
     *
     * @param top represents the new element to be added
     * @return a {@code Stack} with {@code top} on it
     */
    Stack<E> push(E top);

    /**
     * removes the top element of the {@code Stack}
     *
     * @return a {@code Stack} without the top element
     */
    Stack<E> pop();

    /**
     * @return if {@code Stack} is empty {@code Optional.empty};
     * otherwise {@code Optional.of(E)} where {@code E} is the top element
     */
    Optional<E> top();
}
```

The `EmptyStack` represents the base case: when a `Stack` has no element. For each method it is easy to predict all return values:

- the `size` is always `0`
- `push()` always will return a `NonEmptyStack` with the new top element and the current instance as the previous version
- `pop()` can't return a top element; so it always will return an `EmptyStack`
- `top()` can't return a top element; so it always will return an `Optional.empty`

```java
class EmptyStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Stack<E> push(E top) {
        return new NonEmptyStack<>(top, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Stack<E> pop() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> top() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

On the other hand there is the `NonEmptyStack` which represents a `Stack` that contains elements. A `NonEmptyStack` is made up of its element on the top and a `Stack` as its tail, which represents the previous version.

- the `size` is always the size of the previous version plus 1 for the new top element
- `push()` always will return a `NonEmptyStack` with the new top element and the current instance as the previous version
- `pop()` always returns the tail
- `top()` always returns the element which represents the top and since it can be `null` I used `Optional.ofNullable`

```java
class NonEmptyStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

    private final Stack<E> tail;
    private final E top;

    NonEmptyStack(E top, Stack<E> tail) {
        this.tail = tail;
        this.top = top;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 1 + tail.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Stack<E> push(E top) {
        return new NonEmptyStack<>(top, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Stack<E> pop() {
        return tail;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E> top() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(top);
    }

}
```

`EmptyStack` and `NonEmptyStack` are package-private therewith a client only interacts with a `Stack` instead of two different implementations of it. For that I created a Factory `StackFactory` which returns an `EmptyStack` as a `Stack` and the clients never interacts directly with a concrete implementation.

```java
public class StackFactory<E> {

    public Stack<E> create() {
        return new EmptyStack<>();
    }

}
```

## Unit Tests

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class EmptyStackTest {

    private final Stack<String> EMPTY_STACK = new EmptyStack<>();

    @Test
    void givenAnEmptyStack_whenQueryTheSize_thenExpect0() {
        // arrange
        // act
        int size = EMPTY_STACK.size();
        // assert
        assertEquals(0, size);
    }

    @Test
    void givenAnEmptyStack_whenPushAnElementToIt_thenExpectANonEmptyStack() {
        // arrange
        // act
        Stack<String> stack = EMPTY_STACK.push("first");
        // assert
        assertTrue(stack instanceof NonEmptyStack);
    }

    @Test
    void givenAnEmptyStack_whenRemoveTheFirstElement_thenExpectAnEmptyStack() {
        // arrange
        // act
        Stack<String> stack = EMPTY_STACK.pop();
        // assert
        assertTrue(stack instanceof EmptyStack);
    }

    @Test
    void givenAnEmptyStack_whenAccessTopElement_thenExpectItDoNotExists() {
        // arrange
        // act
        Optional<String> top = EMPTY_STACK.top();
        // assert
        assertTrue(!top.isPresent());
    }

}
```

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class NonEmptyStackTest {

    private final String ITEM = "first";

    @Test
    void givenEmptyStackAndItem_whenInstantiateAndQueryTheSize_thenExpect1() {
        // arrange
        Stack<String> stack = new NonEmptyStack<>(ITEM, new EmptyStack<>());
        // act
        int size = stack.size();
        // assert
        assertEquals(1, size);
    }

    @Test
    void givenNonEmptyStackWitOneItemAndANewItem_whenInstantiateAndQueryTheSize_thenExpect2() {
        // arrange
        NonEmptyStack<String> nonEmptyStack = new NonEmptyStack<>(ITEM, new EmptyStack<>());
        Stack<String> stack = new NonEmptyStack<>(ITEM, nonEmptyStack);
        // act
        int size = stack.size();
        // assert
        assertEquals(2, size);
    }

    @Test
    void givenEmptyStackAndItem_whenPushTheItemToTheStack_thenTheItemShouldBeInTheStack() {
        // arrange
        Stack<String> stack = new EmptyStack<>();
        // act
        Stack<String> nonEmptyStack = stack.push(ITEM);
        // assert
        assertEquals(Optional.of(ITEM), nonEmptyStack.top());
    }

    @Test
    void givenNonEmptyStackAndItem_whenPushTheItemToTheStack_thenTheItemShouldBeInTheStack() {
        // arrange
        Stack<String> emptyStack = new EmptyStack<>();
        Stack<String> firstChange = emptyStack.push("value");
        // act
        Stack<String> stack = firstChange.push(ITEM);
        // assert
        assertEquals(Optional.of(ITEM), stack.top());
    }

    @Test
    void givenNonEmptyStackWithOneItem_whenRemoveTheTopItem_thenExpectEmptyStack() {
        // arrange
        Stack<String> testCandidate = new NonEmptyStack<>(ITEM, new EmptyStack<>());
        // act
        Stack<String> stack = testCandidate.pop();
        // assert
        assertTrue(stack instanceof EmptyStack);
    }

    @Test
    void givenNonEmptyStackWithTwoItems_whenRemoveTheTopItem_thenExpectNonEmptyStack() {
        // arrange
        Stack<String> testCandidate = new NonEmptyStack<>(ITEM, new EmptyStack<>()).push(ITEM);
        // act
        Stack<String> stack = testCandidate.pop();
        // assert
        assertTrue(stack instanceof NonEmptyStack);
    }

    @Test
    void givenNonEmptyStack_whenQueryTopItem_thenExpectTopItem() {
        // arrange
        Stack<String> stack = new NonEmptyStack<>(ITEM, new EmptyStack<>());
        // act
        Optional<String> top = stack.top();
        // assert
        assertEquals(Optional.of(ITEM), top);
    }

}
```

## Example

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<String> stack = new StackFactory<String>().create()
                                                        .push("first")
                                                        .push("second")
                                                        .push("third");

        Stack<String> modified = stack.pop()
                                      .pop();

        modified.top()
                .ifPresent(System.out::println); // "first"

        modified.pop()
                .top()
                .ifPresent(System.out::println); // nothing happens 

    }
}
```

---

This little experiment was very entertaining. I appreciate every feedback and thank you very much for reading my code! :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this implementation, `null` entries are problematic. From the public interface, it is impossible to tell if the stack has a null entry, or has reached the bottom: in both cases, `top()` will return `Optional.empty()`.

It seems wrong to silently convert `null`s into `Optional.empty()`s. I would do one of the following:

1. Do not store `null` entries in the stack. Instead, throw an exception on `push`ing a `null` value.
2. Stop using `Optional`s and instead throw an exception when `top` is called on an empty stack. Add an `empty` method to determine if the stack is empty.

Other than that, very clean simple code! A few smaller comments.

Note that `push` has the same implementation in both `EmptyStack` and `NonEmptyStack`. If you like, they could inherit from a single abstract class implementing `push`. This is a judgement call: repeated code is kinda bad, but adding a whole new abstract class is complicated. Perhaps the the cure is worse than the disease...

Computing `size` is slow: time O(n). If you are worried about this, you could compute and store the size in the constructor.

Comment: Since Java 8, methods defined in an interface can have a default implementation. So you wouldn't have to create a separate abstract class to avoid the code duplication in the `push` methods.

Answer (score 3):

The need to instantiate a `StackFactory` in order to create a `Stack` seems superfluous. I would suggest making `create()` a `static` method, which in turn would mean that, instead of the class `StackFactory`, it will be the method `create()` that needs a type parameter:

```java
public class StackFactory {

    public static <E> Stack<E> create() {
        return new EmptyStack<>(); //compiler can infer the type parameter for the newly created Stack from the method's return type
    }
}
```

Then you can call the method like this:

```java
Stack<String> stack = StackFactory.<String>create()
        .push("first")
        .push("second")
        .push("third");
```

Note that, in the above example, you need to explicitly pass the type parameter `String` to the method `create()`, because the newly created `Stack` is not directly assigned to a variable of type `Stack<String>` and the compiler can therefore not infer the type parameter `E` for the call to the method `<E> create()` to be `String`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point out, that it's unnecessary to create a new instance of `EmptyStack` every time you need an empty stack. A single static instance can be used. Additionally `StackFactory` can be avoided by having a static factory method in `EmptyStack`.

```
public class EmptyStack<E> implements Stack<E> {

    private static final Stack<?> INSTANCE = new EmptyStack<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <X> Stack<X> instance() {
        return (Stack<X>) INSTANCE;
    }

    private EmptyStack() {}

    // ...

}
```

For a nicer API, I'd add a static `empty()` method to the `Stack` interface:

```
public interface Stack<E> {

    public static <X> Stack<X> empty() {
     return EmptyStack.instance();
    }

    // ...
}
```